# How to delete chars in string by position only?

Tags: regex, vbscript

I need a regex search & replace pair that will delete 'n' characters from a string, starting at some definable location.  For example, to delete 3 characters starting at position 5.  In that case the string

> AAA. 01 Data From July

would become

> AAA. Data from July

(Don't know if I've started counting at the right spot re 0/1.  That's one reason I need a general solution.)

It can be assumed that the strings will be long enough to support the operation, but it would be very good if it does nothing on too short a string.

The app I'm working within has a VBScript regex engine.  I've searched the web for every variation on this request I can imagine but even with all the regex advice out there this seems to be new.  I thought it would be almost cookbook.  I've also tried doing it myself but can't figure out how to position the engine at the capture point.

Comment: You should do this with string lengths and substrings, not regex.

Comment: Wish that was an option, but I only have regex.  I thought the solution would be to capture the first group (5 in this case), then move 3 more chars, then capture the last group.  Then do a replace with only the two captured groups.  But I can't write it.

Comment: You're using VBScript and you don't have the option to use substrings?

Comment: I'm not using VBScript.  The app I'm using has a regex engine which is part of VBScript.  That's how it was described to me.

Comment: @user3757155 so, you have an equation to solve like `text = regex_replace(pattern, orgtext);` Where `pattern` is the only thing you can control? Please provide more options about that *app*. You need to be able to configure at least 2 parameters: *Pattern* and *replacement* ?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming, your app contains the options to configure the replacement, you could use a backreference-replacement like this:

```
(.{5}).{3}(.*)
```

- `(.{5})` matches the first 5 characters
- `.{3}` consumes the next 3 characters
- `(.*)` matches all remaining charaters

The backreference-replacement `\1\2` (depending on application `\\1\\2` or `$1$2`) will concatenate match group one and two, so basically removing the three characters of the second expression, because they are not forming a match group.

https://regex101.com/r/aC8fQ9/2

Comment: Thank you dognose.  That's exactly what I needed.  I hope it will help others too, because it doesn't appear readily in web searches.

Answer (score 0):

With fixed positions/lengths you could also use the [`Mid`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wffts6k3%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) function:

```vb
Function RemoveSubstring(str, start, length)
  RemoveSubstring = Mid(str, 1, start - 1) & Mid(str, start + length)
End Function
```